# Elements of a nested collection in a smart contract won't persist

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

In NEAR testnet I have this Rust code of a smart contract which works oddly -- elements of a **nested** collection - `Lottery.lottery_obj.users` - won't persist between calls.

```rust
    pub struct Lottery {
        items: TreeMap<LotteryId, LotteryItem>,
        //....
    }

    pub struct LotteryItem {
        //......
        lottery_id: LotteryId, //GUID as string
        users: TreeMap<AccountId, User>,
    }

#[near_bindgen]
impl Lottery {

    //......
    #[init]
    pub fn init() -> Self {
        let items: TreeMap<LotteryId, LotteryItem> = TreeMap::new(b"t");
        Self {
          //.....
          items,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_lottery(&mut self, lottery_id: LotteryId) -> Option<LotteryId> {
        if !self.items.contains_key(&lottery_id) {
            let users: TreeMap<AccountId, Participant> = TreeMap::new(lottery_id.as_bytes());
            let new_item = LotteryItem { lottery_id, users };
            self.items.insert(&lottery_id.clone(), &new_item);
        } else {
            log!("lottery_id '{}' already exists; generate a new one", lottery_id);
            None
        }
    }

    //
    // 1
    //
    // lottery.users.len() == 0 always
    // unless I add an element and check its len() right away
    // next call it'll get 0 again
    //
    pub fn add_user(&self, lottery_id: LotteryId, user_account_id: AccountId) {
        let mut lottery = self.items.get(&lottery_id).unwrap();

        //always zero
        log!("users.len {}", lottery.users.len())

        if lottery.users.contains_key(&user_account_id) {
          log!("user {} already exists")
        } else {
            let new_user = User {
                name: "random_one",
            };

            lottery.users.insert(&user_account_id, &new_user);

            //BUT NOW IT'S 1
            log!("users.len {}", lottery.users.len())
        }
    }


    //
    //2
    //
    // always returns None
    pub fn get_user(&self, lottery_id: LotteryId, user_account_id: AccountId) -> Option<User> {
        let mut lottery = self.items.get(&lottery_id).unwrap();

        //always zero
        log!("users.len {}", lottery.users.len())

        lottery.users.get(&user_account_id)
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, the collection `lottery_obj.users` always remains empty **between calls** -- when I call the methods of a smart contract from the outside.

Each new method call `lottery_obj.users.len()` will be 0!

It only will get non empty **within** a call -- once I've added an element in it and then check its `len()`.

The `Lottery.items` collection do work correctly, though - no elements will disappear.

What cases this? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on Discord (Links [here](https://discord.com/channels/490367152054992913/542945453533036544/1042134680633352332) and [with code](https://discord.com/channels/490367152054992913/542945453533036544/1042142777489756282)). For posterity, the answer was this:

The parent collection was not updated when the nested collection was modified, so the metadata (including how many elements in the map) was not updated.

This error pattern is documented https://docs.near.org/sdk/rust/contract-structure/nesting#error-prone-patterns as "Bug 2"

Modified `add_user` method:

```rust
pub fn add_user(&self, lottery_id: LotteryId, user_account_id: AccountId) {
    let mut lottery = self.items.get(&lottery_id).unwrap();

    //always 0
    log!("users.len {}", lottery.users.len())

    if lottery.users.contains_key(&user_account_id) {
      log!("user {} already exists")
    } else {
        let new_user = User {
            name: "random_one",
        };

        lottery.users.insert(&user_account_id, &new_user);

        //BUT NOW IT'S 1
        log!("users.len {}", lottery.users.len())

        //* FIX: need to insert the item back to update
        self.items.insert(&lottery_id, &lottery);
    }
}
```

Comment: you got me......